# LeetCode 155. Min Stack

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, stack

I am trying to solve the problem using extra space. In the `pop()` function, when I compare the top of both the stacks inside the `if` condition, the following test case is failing:
`["MinStack","push","push","push","push","pop","getMin","pop","getMin","pop","getMin"]\ [[],[512],[-1024],[-1024],[512],[],[],[],[],[],[]]`

When I store the top of the first stack and then compare it with the top of the second stack, all the test cases pass.

Can someone please help me understand what is causing this?

The below code caused the test case to fail.

```java
class MinStack {

    Stack<Integer> s;
    Stack<Integer> auxStack;

    public MinStack() {
        s = new Stack<Integer>();
        auxStack = new Stack<Integer>();
    }
    
    public void push(int val) {
        this.s.push(val);
        if (this.auxStack.empty() || val <= this.auxStack.peek()) {
            this.auxStack.push(val);
        }
    }
    
    public void pop() {
        if (this.s.peek() == this.auxStack.peek()) {
            this.auxStack.pop();
        }
        this.s.pop();
    }
    
    public int top() {
        return this.s.peek();
    }
    
    public int getMin() {
        return this.auxStack.peek();
    }
}
```

The below code worked for all the test cases.

```java
class MinStack {

    Stack<Integer> s;
    Stack<Integer> auxStack;

    public MinStack() {
        s = new Stack<Integer>();
        auxStack = new Stack<Integer>();
    }
    
    public void push(int val) {
        this.s.push(val);
        if (this.auxStack.empty() || val <= this.auxStack.peek()) {
            this.auxStack.push(val);
        }
    }
    
    public void pop() {
        int ans = this.s.pop();
        if (ans == this.auxStack.peek()) {
            this.auxStack.pop();
        }
    }
    
    public int top() {
        return this.s.peek();
    }
    
    public int getMin() {
        return this.auxStack.peek();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are comparing `Integer` objects, not `int` values. The data type stored on the stack is `Integer`. So the `peek()` method returns an `Integer`, not `int`, which means that the following comparison is always false:

```
this.s.peek() == this.auxStack.peek()
```

Fix this by explicitly converting at least one of those two `Integer` objects to an `int`:

```
this.s.peek().intValue() == this.auxStack.peek()
```

Or use the `equals` method:

```
this.s.peek().equals(this.auxStack.peek())
```

Comment: Got it! Thanks.
Just wanted to confirm further:
public void pop() {
        int ans = this.s.pop();
        if (ans == this.auxStack.peek()) {
            this.auxStack.pop();
        }
    }
In the above snippet, since we are storing the top of stack s in 'int' variable, and then comparing the int with Integer object, the integer object value is casted to int automatically and hence we get the correct output. Is my understanding correct here?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.